# Controller interceptor that process endpoint annotation in WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

My team is in the middle of migrating our Spring MVC extensions to WebFlux.

We've got a feature that lets our clients customize metric of controller method. To do that we've created our annotation that is processed by HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

The problem is that I can't see any equivalent of this in Spring WebFlux. I can't use WebFilter because Spring does not know yet which endpoint will be called. How can I implement that?

The closest workaround I found is to use RequestMappingHandlerMapping and somehow build a map of `Map<String(path), HandlerMethod>`, but this is cumbersome and error prone in my opinion.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Edit:

It goes like this

```
public class MeteredHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

public MeteredHandlerInterceptor() {
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // I save start time of method
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    // I read endpoint method from the HandlerMethod, I apply any customisation by our custom @MeteredEndpoint annotation (for example custom name) and I save it in MeterRegistry
}
}
```

I haven't coded workaround yet because I didn't want to invest time in it, but I see that I could obtain `HandlerMethod` for path, but I'm not sure I will receive same `HandlerMethod` as I normally would when the controller is called.

Comment: Do you mind posting a little summary of the code for the original implementation so we can get an idea about what you were doing there? Please also post the workaround you're using

Answer (score 1):

Maybe little bit late, but it can still be useful for someone...

I have not found an easy way to do that, the best I was able to create is a `HandlerAdapter` bean that intercepts handling in the following way:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
    return new HandlerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Object handler) {
            return handler instanceof HandlerMethod;
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<HandlerResult> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Object handler) {
            // your stuff here...
            // e.g. ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethod().getAnnotations()...
            return requestMappingHandlerAdapter.handle(exchange, handler);
        }
    };
}
```

The idea is that this adapter is used for all `HandlerMethod` handlers (those are the ones created by collecting annotated methods from `@Controllers`) and delegates the handling to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` (that would be used directly for `HandlerMethod` handlers in normal case, notice the @Order annotation here).

The point is you can put your code before/after the invocation of the handle method and you are aware of the method being invoked at this point.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please? How is this supposed to be used with the webfilter? Thank you

Comment: Which WebFilter do you mean? The code snippet does not require any explicit WebFilter registration.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought this was somehow supposed to be used with a webflux webfilter (like the one in the answer below from Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
     @Component
 class AuditWebFilter(
      private val requestMapping: RequestMappingHandlerMapping
 ): WebFilter {

      override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
           // if not to call - then exchange.attributes will be empty
           // so little early initialize exchange.attributes by calling next line
           requestMapping.getHandler(exchange)

           val handlerFunction = exchange.attributes.get(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE) as HandlerMethod
           val annotationMethod = handlerFunction.method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation::class.java)

           // annotationMethod  proccesing here
      }
 }
```